# Kotlin: Json: conflicting annotation schemes for name transcription

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, gson

I read data from Firebase database into a Kotlin/Android program. The key names in Firebase are different from those of the corresponding Kotlin variables. I test this code with flat JSON files (for good reasons) where I retain the same key names used in Firebase, so I need to transcribe them too.

Firebase wants to annotate variables with @PropertyName; but Gson, which I use to read flat files, wants @SerializedName (which Firebase doesn't understand, unfortunately.)

Through trial and error I found that this happens to work:

```
@SerializedName("seq")
var id: Int? = null
    @PropertyName("seq")
    get
    @PropertyName("seq")
    set
```

Both Firebase and Gson do their thing and my class gets its data. Am I hanging by a thin thread here? Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!,

Comment: Maybe you could use Kotlin's [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) annotation to avoid having to annotate both the getter and setter (though it is not unlikely that there is a cleaner solution). For Gson, an inefficient workaround could be to first deserialize as `JsonObject`, then inspect the fields of the class and for every `@PropertyName` rename the property in the `JsonObject` from the `@PropertyName` value to the field value, and then let Gson deserialize it again. Other JSON frameworks might support this better.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved to adding an intermediary class (whose var names are the same as the Firebase keys). Those annotations made me lose sleep :)

Comment: My comment was a bit incorrect; Gson's `FieldNamingStrategy` supports getting the annotation from the field (I completely forgot to consider that). I have now written a proper answer describing this. But if you have already found a solution to your problem, then that is great as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably solve this by using Kotlin's [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) to suppress generation of getters and setters. This should allow you to place the `@PropertyName` annotation directly on the property. You can then implement a Gson [`FieldNamingStrategy`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html) which checks if a `@PropertyName` annotation is present on the field and in that case uses its value; otherwise it could return the field name. The `FieldNamingStrategy` has to be [set on a `GsonBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setFieldNamingStrategy(com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy)) which you then use to create the `Gson` instance.